# Extract 12 bits that carry information from a data stream in Python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, deserialization, bitwise-operators, data-stream

I am working on the implementation of the serial driver of the EEG (time-series acquisition device). The device encodes the data with 12bits x 26 total channels with a sampling rate of 200Hz

The serial data stream consists of signalling byte 0xA0 followed by 45 bytes that carry the data for 26 channels, each encoded with 12bits.

But here is the catch, these 12bits are not in fixed positions in the 45byte block. The first byes use only 4 LSB, whilst the rest 44 7 LSB.

To make this more illustrative I will try to represent it graphically below. Suppose that we have started the amplifier and it always gives us 4095 (max int value represented with 12bits) for all channels (so we have all "ones" for the data), then we have something like this:

**a0** 0f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f 7f **a0** next sample...

This has to be mapped to the int(1,...,26) with values 4095.

[image]

So, I made a python code, that first finds the beginning of the block, then it saves everything in one int/long, then I removed the bits on fixed positions, append 8 most significant 0 bits to make a 16bit representation and convert the byte array to a list of integers.

That works fine, but the problem is the speed. Seems that the code takes a considering amount of time for a single sample and it has to do it 200 times in one second. Let's include some other delays of the real serial read methods, everything has to stay much below 1sec for all 200 samples

```
#Python code
def readByte():
#mockup
    return 0xA0

def read45bytes():
    return      int(0x0f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f)


def remove_bit(num, i):
    mask = num >> (i + 1)
    mask = mask << i
    right = ((1 << i) - 1) & num
    return mask | right

def insert_mult_bits(num, bits, len, i):
    mask = num >> i
    mask = (mask << len) | bits
    mask = mask << i
    right = ((1 << i) - 1) & num
    return right | mask



def main():

    while(readByte()!=0xA0):
        print("Searching for the beginning of the packet of 45 bytes...")

    print("Beginning of the packet of 45 bytes found")



    #read whole sample
    sample=read45bytes()

    #remove unused bits
    corr=0;
    for i in range(7, sample.bit_length(), 8):
        sample=remove_bit(sample,i-corr);
        corr=corr+1;

    #add HSB to make 2byte representation
    corr=0;
    for i in range(12,sample.bit_length(),12):
        sample=insert_mult_bits(sample,0,4,i+corr)
        corr=corr+4;

    #convert to bytes 26channels x 2 bytes, bigendian
    bt=sample.to_bytes(26*2,'big');

    #assign the result to int list
    idx=0;
    out=[];
    for i in range(0,26*2-1,2):
        out.append(int(int((bt[i]<<8 | bt[i+1]))))
        idx=idx+1;

    #print first sample of the channel 1
    print(out.pop(0))
```

Comment: I'm curious, why are these 12 bits spaced out so irregularly? 3 bytes = 24 bits, which should align with 2 channels perfectly. Are the skipped 0s perhaps some sort of error-detection you should be checking?

Comment: I am not sure, I suppose bandwidth limitation. I thought also that "0" are some kind of error correction, but then I realized that it is a design limitation, as the marker byte uses MSB to mark the beginning of the sequence. Also, serial is mostly read byte per byte, maybe they assumed that it is easy to discard the first byte once you receive a byte?! Unfortunately, I cannot change the communication protocol of the device.

Comment: Have you tried to *profile* your code? If not please do that, as this will allow you find most time consuming part (so-called *bottleneck*) at which you should focus your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import math
import io
import itertools as it


START_MARKER = b"\xA0"
START_MARKER_LEN = len(START_MARKER)

BIT_VALUE_MASK = list(2 ** i for i in range(7, -1, -1))

IGNORED_BITS_INDEXES = (7,)


def chunk_size(channel_count=26, bits_per_channel=12, ignored_bits_indexes=IGNORED_BITS_INDEXES, ignored_heading_bits=4):
    libi = len(ignored_bits_indexes)
    #if libi > 7:
    #    raise ValueError
    bits = channel_count * bits_per_channel
    bpb = 8 - libi
    q, r = divmod(bits, bpb)
    r += ignored_heading_bits
    return q + math.ceil(r / 8)


def byte_2_bits(byte):
    return [1 if (byte & i) else 0 for i in BIT_VALUE_MASK]


def bits_2_val(bits):
    return sum(2 ** idx if bit == 1 else 0 for idx, bit in enumerate(bits[::-1]))


def decode_chunk(chunk, bits_per_channel=12, ignored_bits_indexes=IGNORED_BITS_INDEXES, ignored_heading_bits=4):
    bit_lists = [reversed(byte_2_bits(b)) for b in chunk[::-1]]
    bits = list(it.chain(*bit_lists))
    channels = []
    cur_chan_bits = []
    for idx, bit in enumerate(bits[:-ignored_heading_bits]):
        if idx % 8 in ignored_bits_indexes:
            continue
        cur_chan_bits.append(bit)
        if len(cur_chan_bits) == bits_per_channel:
            channels.append(bits_2_val(cur_chan_bits[::-1]))
            cur_chan_bits = []
    if cur_chan_bits:
        raise ValueError("Something went wrong while decoding: ", cur_chan_bits)
    return channels[::-1]


def read_data(stream, channel_count=26, bits_per_channel=12, ignored_bits_indexes=IGNORED_BITS_INDEXES, ignored_heading_bits=4):
    while 1:
        t = stream.read(START_MARKER_LEN)
        if not t:
            break
        if t != START_MARKER:
            continue
        print("Start marker...")
        size = chunk_size(channel_count=channel_count, bits_per_channel=bits_per_channel, ignored_bits_indexes=ignored_bits_indexes, ignored_heading_bits=ignored_heading_bits)
        chunk = stream.read(size)
        if len(chunk) == size:
            decoded = decode_chunk(chunk, bits_per_channel=bits_per_channel, ignored_bits_indexes=ignored_bits_indexes, ignored_heading_bits=ignored_heading_bits)
            print("Decoded: {:}\n".format(decoded))
    print("End of data.")


def main(*argv):
                         # 1st chunk is the one in the question, I played a bit with next ones
    b =   START_MARKER + b"\x0F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F" \
        + START_MARKER + b"\x0F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7E" \
        + START_MARKER + b"\x0F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x60\x01" \
        + START_MARKER + b"\x0F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x5F\x7F" \
        + START_MARKER + b"\x00\x00\x3F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F"

    read_data(io.BytesIO(b))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Notes**:

- This approach (almost) doesn't use bit operations, instead it handles bits in a number (byte) as a list of numbers (possible values: 0, 1)
- Decoding (on a complete chunk of data):

  1. Reverse:

     1. All the bytes in the chunk
     2. All the bits in each byte

     to get the chunk bits in reversed order
  2. Traverse the bit list (skipping 7<sup>th</sup> bit of each byte), and when 12 bits are encountered, convert them in reversed order (to "undo" the **bit** reverse from ***#1.2.***) to a channel value which is added to the channel list
  3. Return the channel list in reversed order (to "undo" the **byte** reverse from ***#1.1.***)
- Some utility functions (pretty straightforward I guess) are used
- Better error handling could be added

**Output**:

> ```bash
> py_pc064_03_08_test0) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q069660629]> python code00.py 
> Python 3.8.10 (default, Sep 28 2021, 16:10:42) [GCC 9.3.0] 064bit on linux
>
> Start marker...
> Decoded: [4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095]
>
> Start marker...
> Decoded: [4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4094]
>
> Start marker...
> Decoded: [4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 1]
>
> Start marker...
> Decoded: [4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4094, 4095]
>
> Start marker...
> Decoded: [0, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095]
>
> End of data.
>
> Done.
> ```

Comment: Thx a lot. Works as a charm!!!

Answer (score 0):

CristiFati's solution is smart, and works well. However I find it a bit difficult to understand at a first sight (my fault, of course), and although fast enough for the use case it is not as fast as it could be. So I tried to find something simpler, and faster.

My reasoning is: once the start marker is found, we can precompute the positions of the data bits for each channel. For instance channel 0 will use bits 4-7 from byte 0, bits 1-7 from byte 1, and bit 1 from byte 2; channel 1 will use bits 2-7 from byte 2, and bits 1-6 from byte 3; and so on. Note that since the data lenght is 12 bits every channel will span over 2 or 3 bytes.

Take channel 1: we use 4 bits of the first byte so we mask it against `2**4-1`, and then we need to multiply it by `2**8`, since we still have other 8 bits to consider; then for the second byte, we use 7 bits so we mask it against `2**7-1`, and multiply it by `2**1`. The last byte is different: we first divide it by `2**6` to clear the bits that belong to the next channel, then mask it against `2**1-1`.

So for each channel we can store a tuple recording the byte position, the bit mask needed to select the relevant bits, and the number of bits that we need to shift: to the right for the last byte of the channel, to the left for the previous byte(s).

The important point is, this setup part needs to be performed just once. After that we can just read our chunks and apply the calculations we need:

```
import io

MARK = b"\xA0"

def set_specs():
    CHANNELS_NO = 26
    CHANNEL_SIZE = 12
    BYTE_SIZE = 8
    MARX = b"\xA0"
    bitoffset = 4
    currbyte = 1
    
    chspecs = []
    for ch in range(CHANNELS_NO):
        needed = CHANNEL_SIZE
        spec = []
        while needed > 0:
            available = BYTE_SIZE - bitoffset
            if needed > available:
                mask = 2**available - 1
                needed -= available
                lshift = needed
                spec.append((currbyte, mask, lshift))
                currbyte += 1
                bitoffset = 1
            else:
                mask = 2**needed - 1
                rshift = available - needed
                bitoffset += needed
                needed = 0
                spec.append((currbyte, mask, rshift))
        chspecs.append(spec)
    return chspecs

def do_read(chspecs, data):
    chvals = []
    databytes = io.BytesIO(data).read()
    for spec in chspecs:
        chval = 0
        for currbyte, mask, lshift in spec[:-1]:
            chval += (databytes[currbyte] & mask) << lshift
        currbyte, mask, rshift = spec[-1]
        chval += (databytes[currbyte] >> rshift) & mask
        chvals.append(chval)
    return chvals

specs = set_specs()
data = b"\xA0\x0F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F\x7F"
vals = do_read(specs, data)
```

This is about 170x faster on my PC.

Important note: if I understand correctly, your device sends the start marker together with the first 4 bits of data, so you will (almost) never receive a "\xA0" byte: if we stay with the assumption that all data bits are "1"s what you will receive is "\xAF". In fact the `len` of the sample data we're using is 46, not 45. So, since this part was unclear to me, I just skipped it: I ignore byte 0, and start reading the 4 less significant bits of byte 1.